# ¿Cómo puedo añadir mi pagina web que hice en visual studio code a vs?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, css, asp.net-core-mvc

Saludos comunidad de programación, tengo una duda, quiero subir mi plantilla de mi pagina web que hice en visual studio code a visual studio pero quiero subirla a través de una soluciona llamada **ASP.Net core web application (Model-View-Controller).** La versión que estoy usando del **framework es 5.0** Pero una vez estando dentro de la solución no se por donde empezar, ya conozco un poco el tema de las vistas, controladores y modelos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Con subirla te referís a agregar tu plantilla a tu proyecto en Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear primero tu proyecto web net core y luego solo reemplazar los archivos js y los css. Ten en cuenta que en el archivo _layout.cshtml va lo que seria el encabezado y pie de pagina para todas las vistas, y en cada vista u archivo cshtml solo debes pegar lo que seria el body sin la etiqueta  ya que esa parte va inlcuida dentro del _layout.cshtml donde dice @RenderBody

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear primero tu proyecto web net core y luego solo reemplazar los archivos js y los css. Ten en cuenta que en el archivo _layout.cshtml va lo que seria el encabezado y pie de pagina para todas las vistas, y en cada vista u archivo cshtml solo debes pegar lo que seria el body sin la etiqueta ya que esa parte va inlcuida dentro del _layout.cshtml donde dice @RenderBody

Comment: ¿Por qué copiaste tal cual [esta respuesta](/a/570875)?